# Avoid truncating error message in Powershell error

Tags: powershell-v4.0

I'm getting a Powershell error like this:

```
PS C:\mydirectory> $Error[0]
Get-WmiObject : 
At line:143 char:13
+           $Disk = Get-WmiObject MSCluster_Disk -ComputerName $Resource.OwnerNode -Auth    ...
+    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-WmiObject], COMException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMICOMException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
```

Is there a way I can avoid the command that triggered the error (i.e., `$Disk = Get-WmiObject MSCluster_Disk ...`) being truncated in the error message?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This can be found in the error object. `$Error` is an array of errors, and `[0]` is the most recent. That's actually an object that can be interrogated...

```
($Error[0]).InvocationInfo.Line
```

Will give you the full line in the script that generated the error. The `InvocationInfo` property will not exist for errors from the command line.

Other nice properties you can get are `PSScriptRoot` which gives you the path to the script file, `ScriptName` which gives you the file name, and `ScriptLineNumber` which gives you the line in the script that failed.